# When using MutationObserver to track DOM change events how can one get the timestamp of the event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers

I am using MutationObserver to track changes to the DOM and the code is working fine at the moment but I need to add in a timestamp for the event.   There does not appear to be a timestamp property off the MutationRecord

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

I've drilled successively in  `__proto__` of the MutationRecord and could not find much.  How can I get the timestamp of the event creation please?

Comment: Well, it's not part of the API so you won't get it. Anyway, MO's callback is executed as microtask usually immediately (that is in microseconds) after the change, so why do you need a timestamp?

Comment: Ok, I guess I can use the current time, just thought there might be a timestamp buried in the object creation somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Before using that `MutationRecord`, do `record.timestamp=performance.now();`